# Is it possible to setup a private network with DNS lookup using app_rpt?

Tags: repeater, linux, internet

I am going through a bit of a headache trying to find this information. I have a lot of people interested in a private simplex node/repeater network using Asterisk/app_rpt, the same software AllStarLink uses. Instead of using dynamic DNS or OpenVPN, I would like to use their technique on node lookup, that is, DNS. They state in their wiki that they utilize a PowerDNS server with MySQL. How would I go about doing this? I hope I am asking in the right place. I know how it works, I just don't know how to implement it on my system. I would preferably want to know how HamVoIP does it as well. The way I am doing it now is everybody hears everybody by everyone connecting to a central hub. I don't want that type of system. Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Interesting!  Sounds like you might need to write some code.  We have some very bright people here who are experts in many subjects, and I hope that someone here has the expertise to help.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the welcoming! Yeah, I wouldn't mind writing some code, that's how I think they do it, is using a combination of bash scripts on the user nodes and php/perl scripts on the servers.

Comment: Ooh, in your shoes I'd be seriously considering junking the entire project if I knew I had to write Perl code... (I kid, I've held my nose and edited Perl before.)

Comment: What you're describing *is* dynamic DNS, it's just running the dynamic DNS system yourself instead of using a public one, and using a non-standard update method :)

Comment: Well, what I want to know is how do I get the ip addresses from end user nodes that have the register statement pointing to my server, and put those ip addresses in a zone somehow? That's the part I'm missing. I guess I don't fully understand it.